# Magento 2.1 :- CMS Page and Static Block

Tags: adminhtml, xml, magento-2.1, cms-block, cms-pages

Here one issue in my magento 2.1.
I create one di.xml file for my own module but i got error in cms page and static block.
Check below image for cms page and static block error.

CMS Page:-
[image]

Static Block:-
[image]

And Below my di.xml code for admin panel. (**Job/Test/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool" type="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="testtab" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Job\Test\Ui\Component\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Testtab</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Job\Test\Ui\Component\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Testtab">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="scopeName" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="testtab_test_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Job\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Grid\Collection</item>
                <item name="demo_index_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Job\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grid di.xml is global. So when you create your custom module admin grid, your di.xml should be under **etc** folder, not **etc/adminhtml**. So

Move **Job/Test/etc/adminhtml/di.xml** to **Job/Test/etc/di.xml**

Comment: Sohel, now one issue create when i move Job/Test/etc/adminhtml/di.xml to Job/Test/etc/di.xml in my custom module. I create one tab in admin catalog product page. Now this tab is disappear.

Comment: You move only grid related code. So you need to create two di.xml one under etc and other etc/adminhtml. So your tab related code move to etc/adminhtml/di.xml only.

Comment: Hey Sohel, my issue solve by me for above code. Now both are working perfect. And Thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

I try below code and my issue solved.

**Job/Test/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool" type="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="testtab" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Job\Test\Ui\Component\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Testtab</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1000</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Job\Test\Ui\Component\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Testtab">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="scopeName" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Job/Test/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="testtab_test_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Job\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Grid\Collection</item>
                <item name="demo_index_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Job\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```